# Error while importing ttm-cdTopologystructure

Tags: topology-manager

I am getting the error below while running the PowerShell script.

[image]

The export is successful and the user is part of 'Topology Manager Administrators' windows group

Topology Instance and CD are both in the same server.

Also if I run like the below screenshot, the import is successful but when I hit the URL - http://localhost:81/ttm201501/$metadata#mappings
I don't see any updated mapping data for cdEnvironment, Website, Webapplication etc.

[image]

Comment: As you already figured out yourself, the `UpdateExistingItems` parameter is a so-called flag parameter which you either specify (without value) or not.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell cmdlet syntax you use in your last example is correct.

However, the OData query you are using will **not** give you the TTM Mappings, but only (Schema) metadata about them. Try using the PowerShell cmdlets, for example: `Get-TtmMapping`, `Get-TtmWebsite`, `Get-TtmWebApplication`.

Furthermore, as far as I know, the `Export/Import-TtmCdStructure` cmdlets do not export/import TTM Mappings at all, but only the “structure” of a given CD Environment (i.e. Websites and Web Apps defined for that CD Environment).

Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, if I run the Powershell scripts, I can see the mapping data. Everything looks fine and it gets published successfully to the Broker DB. But when I hit the Application URL, I get the below error:
Page URL path '/navigation.json' in Publication '15' returned no data.
Exception Details: Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Page URL path '/navigation.json' in Publication '15' returned no data.
[DxaException: Page URL path '/navigation.json' in Publication '15' returned no data.]
   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.GraphQLContentProvider.GetPageContent(String urlPath, Localization localization)

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't sound like a problem with your Topology Manager / Discovery Service: note that the Publication ID (15) has already been resolved.  The problem is that you apparently don't have a Page with URL "/navigation.json" (in Publication 15) in your CD Content Store. Did you publish the "Navigation" Page?

Comment: Yes, i published it and i can see in the DB too

Comment: With that URL and Publication ID?  Can you intercept the DB queries (e.g. with SQL Profiler) to understand what's going wrong?